# Wordpress Ajax function on frontend is returning entire html

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I've just started playing around with using Ajax on Wordpress front end. The js is correctly loaded and passes the data, but in return I get an entire html back in response instead of just "ok".

When I navigate to this URL directly, it prints out "OK" correctly: https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=checkins_show

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my set up:

inside `function.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_frontend_ajax_javascript_file' );
function add_frontend_ajax_javascript_file(){
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax_custom_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/checkins.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax_custom_script', 'frontendajax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_checkins_show', 'checkins_show' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_checkins_show', 'checkins_show' );

function checkins_show() {
    echo 'ok';
    die();
}
```

inside `checkins.js`

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var el = $("#checkins_show");
    var loc_id = el.data('locid');
    var url = el.data('href');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: url,
        data: { 
            action: 'checkins_show',
            locid: loc_id
        },
        success : function( response ) {

            console.log(response);

            if( response === 'ok' ) {
                el.html('worked');
            }
        }       
    });

    return false;

});
```

actual html rendered:

```
<div data-locid="111" data-url="https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=checkins_show" id="checkins_show"></div>
```

Comment: when entire html is returned it means that you have incorrect request URI

Comment: When I navigate to this URL directly, it correctly prints out "OK": https://www.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=checkins_show

Comment: it can be different if you are using rwlative path in ajax call, if you are using absolute path than prepend it http://

Comment: btw u have var url = el.data('href'); it should be var url = el.data('url');

Comment: Why not use the `ajaxurl` variable defined by wordpress?

Comment: have you checked in the console network tab ? what header is going ? and what you are getting in response ? by the way why you are doing die() ?

Comment: you should do exit instead of die

Comment: @GuramiDagundaridze thank you for catching that, that was the issue.

Comment: @rajatsaurastri There is no difference what-so-ever.